# Is it true that there is no such thing as forbidden in Hinduism?

Tags: guru, explanation

According to this [scholar](https://www.quora.com/Usually-it-is-forbidden-to-sleep-or-have-food-during-the-time-of-sunset-Sandhya-by-Hindu-However-are-we-even-forbidden-to-study-textbooks-during-that-time/answer/Rami-Sivan?ch=10&share=a4956cb7&srid=ucZAt6) on quora.

> There is no “forbidden” in Hinduism.

Is this true.